# How can I take apart this kind of tap to replace the washer?

Tags: faucet

I need to replace the washer on this tap as it keeps leaking.

The tap design seems quite similar to the one [described here](http://www.ultimatehandyman.co.uk/taps/replacing_tap_washer.htm), but it seems the middle section cannot be turned (it's completely round, doesn't have any nut ridges).

Can this model be taken appart?

[image]
[image]

<strike>The top cap seems to have some notches to be able to turn it, but I think it's actually fused to the handle. Maybe it needs lot of WD40?</strike>

---

## Update:

With lots of fiddling around, the top came off **by turning** (didn't pry up), so those notches actually helped.

[image]

Now, I think the cover should come out by spinning, but there is no way to grab hold to spin it. The tiny notch seems to be more likely a defect, or maybe made by some previous guy attempting to fix it. It's not deep enough to insert a screwdriver to help spin it.

Any ideas on how to proceed next?

[image]

Comment: Those notches are decorative, not meant for turning.

Comment: Thanks, @TheEvilGreebo, but I managed to get the cap off, any ideas next?

Comment: Follow the rest of the steps in the tutorial you linked to. Next remove the "fancy part of the tap" by turning it anti-clockwise...

Comment: @Tester101: I know that's the next step, but I can't grab hold of it to spin it.

Comment: Try [Tongue and groove Pliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-and-groove_pliers). Wrap the "fancy part" with a rag (so you don't scratch it), and don't squeeze too hard (or you could deform it). Or grab it with one hand, then use your other hand to add torque by turning your first hand. Or give it a blast of [Penetrating oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetrating_oil), and let it sit for a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in answers and comments, channel pliers or locking pliers can be used to remove the screwed down cap that hold in the stem (the grooved top of which you show). As indicated, tape or a cloth may reduce the chance of damaging the finish. A wide, thick rubber band is also useful in gripping under pliers to avoid scratches.

An alternative is a [strap wrench](http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/tools/Ratchets-Sockets/wrenches-pipe/grip-it-strap-wrenches-s-6h?utm_source=google_pr&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Wrenches-Pipe-Plumbing-google_pr&infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=CKi-z_2Ns7ICFYWo4AodtHcAxQ).

[image: strap wrench]

It can be used for this purpose and also to turn or hold pipes.

Answer (score 4):

The top cap should simply pry up from the knob.  Then under the cap you should find a screw you can remove to release the handle and access the valve stem.

Shut off the water first, of course. :D

Comment: Thanks, your answer made me try it harder, and I managed to take off the cap, only it was actually screwed in. Any ideas next?

Comment: now the top section will screw off, you will have to use a wrench, be carefull not to damage the copper finish, protect by using a cloth between the grips and the brass cap.. Minor scratches will show excessively now,will blend in over time